# My facebook app does not appear in the search box

Tags: facebook, search

Few weeks ago, i have developped a Facebook app but it never appeared in the search box and I don't really know why... I thought it was just a matter of time before Facebook updates its search box and includes my app in it but it nerver happened.

Is there any mandatory information that I may have forgotten in the app parameters ?

Thanks in advance for your answers :).

Comment: Have you [submitted your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/) to Facebook ?

Comment: Also check whether SANDBOX mode is ON or Social Discovery ON

Comment: Sandbox mode is OFF and Social discovery ON.

Towards the submission, the app isn't submitted but i have another app based on the same PHP pages (just 1 parameter changes to differentiate them) and this other app is online and findable in the search box.

I read the link you gave me about app submission to know more about that.